# WordPress writing HTML differently than functions.php specifies

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is so crazy that I can't think of what could possibly be happening.

I've got a shortcode defined in `functions.php` which looks like this:

```
function company($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "linkto" => 'http://url.com',
    "status" => 'none',
    "size" => 'normal'
), $atts));
return '<a href="'.$linkto.'"><div class="company block size-'.$size.'">'.$content.'<span class="status-'.$status.'"></span></div></a>';
}
add_shortcode("company", "company");
```

This is followed by the usual, documented way of registering the shortcode, and adding buttons to TinyMCE.

The critical part there is that it returns an anchor enclosing a div (which encloses some content). However, when WordPress renders the page, the HTML output is this:

```
<p><a href="http://url.com/"></a></p>
<div class="company block size-normal"><a href="http://url.com/"><img class="aligncompanylogo size-full wp-image-60" alt="logo" src="http://path/to/image.png" width="256" height="60"><span class="status-acquired"></span></a></div>
<a href="http://url.com/">
</a>
<p><a href="http://url.com/"></a></p>
```

You're reading that right: WordPress outputs a p with an anchor first, then the div, followed by the anchor, followed by the content, followed by *third* anchor, and then a *fourth* anchor enclosed in p tags. What.

Any ideas on why WordPress outputs HTML completely differently than the way it's supposed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT #2: when I try to reproduce your problem, I find the following: Wordpress outputs the HTML as expected but the browser rearranges the DOM. I believe the browser is doing this because your shortcode adds a div element inside a p element which is invalid HTML.

In addition to the workarounds posted below you could prevent Wordpress from turning line breaks into p tags by adding the following to functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

<del>Putting a div within an anchor tag is invalid. Is it possible something somewhere is attempting to fix the invalid HTML?</del>

<del>Something in Wordpress is considering a div nested withing an anchor tag invalid and trying to fix it.</del> Two workarounds,

Change your div to a span.

Change your div to another HTML element and make sure TinyMCE considers it valid by adding a hook to functions.php - in this example, I'm changing the div to article and adding article as a valid child of anchor:

```
function modify_valid_children($settings){
    $settings['valid_children']="+a[article]";
    return $settings;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'modify_valid_children');
```

Comment: It's valid in HTML5 (and that's the doctype for this, so I hope it isn't trying to "correct" anything). Also doesn't explain the two additional instances of anchors.

Comment: I changed my answer after looking into it a bit. Hopefully you've found a workaround or one that I posted will suffice.

Comment: This is getting real close – thanks Erik. Before I mark it as solved, is there a way to specify only to run that `remove_filter` on a specific page? I don't want it to be global. Something like a templated functions page?

Comment: Never mind – just added the `remove_filter` to the page template I'm using for the specific page. Thanks!